# Dynamic url path not working in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to create a dynamic url in my Aangualr2 App. I passed the id to the a service and I appended it as below:

```
ServiceDesk/DashBoard/${id}/Gadget
```

When I run my app, it is throwing an error because the url is generated as below instead of id getting replaced with the below string instead of value 1.

```
ServiceDesk/DashBoard/$%7Bid%7D/Gadget
```

Comment: could you add code where you are modifying this URL?

Comment: Please see the code below. This is a  method in my app.service.ts. Basically I need to append the variable id, while making the below http request.When I see the network tab, the ${id} is replaced with $%7Bid%7D, instead of 1.                                                                                      getGadgetsData(id: string) {
        return this._http.get('http://devsrv/API/api/Desk/DashBoard/Gadget/${id}/Data')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());

    }

Comment: have you tried backquote (\`) instead of regular quote ('), \`devsrv/API/api/Desk/DashBoard/Gadget/${id}/D‌​ata\`?

Comment: Works now with the change. Thanks. Appreciate your help.

Comment: great, I will post this answer then and you can accept it :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use backtick or back quote (`) instead of regular quote (').

For example:

```
`devsrv/API/api/Desk/DashBoard/Gadget/${id}/D‌​ata`
```

Comment: any documentation about this?